# Python - increased memory usage when using a wrapper function?

Tags: python, performance, memory, int

I wrote a test for a program and checked the memory usage. For some reason, wrapping the same operation in a function results in a polynomial (or maybe exponential) increase in memory usage. I am using [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to track memory usage, Python 2.7.1.

Code:

```
def convertIntToBitint(number): return (pow(2, number - 1))
```

Test code and results (cleaned up a bit):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
23     9.070 MB     0.000 MB    def test_convertBigIntToBitint(self):
24     9.070 MB     0.000 MB        result1 = convertIntToBitint(21000)
25     9.070 MB     0.000 MB        answer1 = pow(2, 20999)
27    10.496 MB     1.426 MB        result2 = convertIntToBitint(5015280)
28    11.785 MB     1.289 MB        answer2 = pow(2, 5015279)
30    70.621 MB    58.836 MB        result3 = convertIntToBitint(121000000)
31    85.367 MB    14.746 MB        answer3 = pow(2, 120999999)
```

Why does `convertIntToBitint` take up more memory? And why doesn't the memory usage grow linearly?

### EDIT for 2rs2ts

Interesting. Not sure if this is what you meant.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
23     9.074 MB     0.000 MB    def test_convertBigIntToBitint(self):
24    56.691 MB    47.617 MB        result3 = convertIntToBitint(121000000)
25    85.539 MB    28.848 MB        answer3 = pow(2, 120999999)
26    85.539 MB     0.000 MB        result2 = convertIntToBitint(5015280)
27    84.258 MB    -1.281 MB        answer2 = pow(2, 5015279)
28    83.773 MB    -0.484 MB        result1 = convertIntToBitint(21000)
29    81.211 MB    -2.562 MB        answer1 = pow(2, 20999)
```

Comment: I'm just wildly guessing there but, while python can handle very big numbers (a lot bigger than the one you use), it might have to do operations in the background to handle these big numbers, hence the cost in memory.

Comment: How does the performance compare when you call `convertIntToBitint(number-1)` and return `pow(2, number)`?

Comment: You are creating rather large numbers there. Have you taken into account that creating *large* integers also uses memory?

Comment: @2rs2ts The performance is about the same. Martijin, not sure what you are talking about. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you try alternating your `result`/`answer` lines? I have a theory about the allocation.

Comment: What about comparing with pow(2, 121000000-1). In case the allocation of the slightly larger number has something to do with it

Comment: @2rs2ts done. Do you get notifications if I edit the original question?

Comment: A long int is a literal, so it is passed out of the function by value, not by reference. A copy of the long int is probably made inside the function, before it is returned. Maybe this memory is not released (garbage collected?) before the memory profiler makes its measurement?

Comment: MrGreen: I think @Martijin meant that there's additional working memory involved when creating large integers that's not necessarily linearly related to its size. Also, if you want people to be notified of your response to their comments, you should prefix their name with a `'@'`.

Comment: @MrGreen I do not get notifications if you edit the original question. You have to @ mention me in the comments. I meant basically that, although I should have been explicit - I meant `answer1`, `result1`, `answer2`, etc. At any rate, I would write this in an answer but I'm actually not certain of whether it is true - however, I think you are seeing that when you allocate a new long integer, you are actually allocating [a block of integers](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/). Something about the values must affect the behavior of allocation.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with what @AaronLockey said about call by value, not call by reference. The [source code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/intobject.c) might shed some light on why this is.